# Finding items in a table that satisfy a subset frequency condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, frequency, subset

I have a very simple item ownership table with these two columns:

```
UserID, ItemID
```

There is an index on UserID, but not ItemID.

I have a set S of 10-40 specific `ItemID`s (in my queries they are just a comma delimited list of integers).

I want to find all `UserID`s that own at least X (distinct `ItemID`s) of the items in S.

I am using MSSQL if it matters. Can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select UserID
from Ownership 
where ItemID in (1,2,3,4,5,...) --your list of ItemIDs
group by UserID
having count(distinct ItemID) >= 3 --the minimum # of distinct items required
```

Comment: That is the elegant solution I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @RedFilter: Agree. That's why it was [initially called SEQUEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#History) – Structured English QUEry Language.

Comment: Sounds like an internationalization headache!